# send ajax data to controller

Tags: php, ajax

Without using MVC, I would have a page that has some jQuery which makes an ajax call to a specific php page, like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#login" ).on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $( "#loginForm" ).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'somePage.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: form,
        })
        .done(function (data) {
            if(!data.success) {

                console.log(data.message);

            } else {

                console.log(data.message);
            }
        })
        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
                console.warn(jqXHR.responseText);
            });
    });
});
```

somePage.php would look like:

```
if($_POST) {

    $response = array();
    $message = "";

if(empty($_POST['name'])) {

        $message .= "Name required";
    }

if($message) {

        $response['success'] = false;
        $response['message'] = $message;

    } else {

        // add data to database
        $response['success'] = true;
        $response['message'] = "Success";

    }

    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

I am new to MVC and OOP and am just wondering how I would change this because I would need to do the validation in the controller and then send the data to the model for database insert. The purpose of the ajax here is simply prevent page refresh when submitting the form and either display an error message if validation fails or show a success message if passes and then insert data into the database.

This is what my controller looks like at the moment for non ajax submission:

```
public function test() {

        if($_POST) {


            $data = [

                'email' => trim($_POST['email']),
                'email_err' => '' 
            ];

            if(empty($_POST['email'])) {

                $data['email_err'] = 'Email required';
            }

            if(empty($data['email_err'])) {

                //send data to model

            } else {

                $this->view('users/login', $data);
            }

        } else {

            $data = [

                'email' => '',
                'email_err' => ''
            ];

            $this->view('users/login', $data);
        }
    }
```

So, the question is basically how do I get the ajax response to the controller and the model? The error message would be displayed in the view.

Comment: I suggest using a method of routing. Send a request to a dynamic route to execute a method which you then create a controller to use that data.